# How can I save the state of a dynamic table when its activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a TableLayout which I am dynamically adding rows to based on user input. I would like this table to keep its values when the activity is destroyed (i.e rotated, back button).

I'm aware that I could input the values of this table as individual values to a SharedPreferences map, but this would involve manually reconstructing the table when the activity is restored.

Is there a more elegant solution to saving a table other than using SharedPreferences for all of the individual elements?

Comment: serialize your data table class to your internal storage and de-serialise it

Comment: @Elitz Could you provide a bit more information? My data table is a TableLayout, when I serialize and deserialize, how would I commit this back to the layout?

Answer (score 0):

i was referring to saving the items in an data class and serialising that data class eg (`TableLalyoutstorage.java` which has the items to your data), so with that you need to change how your layout receives data, it should first save to your data class object before it adds it..

**BUT**  ( *i have not tried it but you can serialise views* ) you try this too

so if you have a `ViewGroup` which `TableLayout` happens to be one you can do this

```
ArrayList<View> myViews = null; // this is declared globally, view container
// in initialising lifecycles of android eg oncreate
TableLayout tl = View.findViewById(R.id.tl)// thats my initialising of table layout.. 
//we already has or have Views added to it
// all this in my oncreate
FileInputStream fiss;
try {
    fiss = Activity.openFileInput("dataName"); // dataName is the name you want to save it on disk
    ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fiss);
    myViews = ((ArrayList<View>) oi.readObject()); // it will read from disk
    oi.close();
    fiss.close();
}catch(Exception e){}
//after that
if(myViews !=null && !myViews.isEmpty()){
     for(int i = 0; i < myViews.size(); i++){
           tl.addView(myViews.get(i)); // add params and stuff
     }
 }
 // with that your `ViewGroup` now has it views
```

then maybe in your closing lifeclycles you save your views

```
myViews.clear();
for(int i =0; i < tl.getChildCount(); i++){
      myViews.add(tl.getChildAt(i));
   }
// we noww save to disk
try {
   FileOutputStream foss = Activity.openFileOutput("dataName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   ObjectOutputStream off = new ObjectOutputStream(foss);
   off.writeObject(myViews);
   off.flush();
   off.close();
   foss.close();}catch (Exception e) {}
```

don't forget to check my braces, or indenting, i am a pretty bad text code writer..

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Hi Elitz, thanks for your idea and explanation. I tried it, but unfortunately, TableRow is not serializable, and throws a NotSerializableException

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) to persist data that you need to use when activity is restored, and [`onCreate(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) to reconstruct your UI with data previously persisted (if any). This assumes that your data either implements [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or is one of the types that can be added to [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

I never try this approach with `TableLayout` before, probably even with data restoration your view state would change (like scrolling position), but at least you see table with full data as before. Alternatively you can try out [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) or [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), which uses `Adapter` to bind data, and have better support for view state restoration.

Comment: From all of the documentation I've seen, onSaveInstanceState is meant to be used for small-scale data, i.e user name, password, etc. Either way, this wouldn't be much different than saving the values into a SharedPreference state, as I would have to reconstruct the view again manually (which is what I'm trying to avoid). Thanks for the suggestion